# If you can only choose one which way should you learn, bekiyus or beiyun?

Tags: torah-study, priorities

If you can only choose one, which way should you learn, bekiyus (learning quickly on a more superficial level to cover ground) or beiyun (slower, more in depth study)?

---

As a reminder, answers on this site should be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise: please cite your arguments or sources!

Comment: Could you briefly explain what those options mean?

Comment: If you can only eat one of the ingredients in chocolate milk, should you have the chocolate or the milk?

Comment: @DoubleAA the chocolate, of course!

Comment: @DoubleAA what does the milk chocolate correspond to? Is the milk the b'iyun and chocolate the bekius or the other way around?

Comment: They don't correspond to anything. You need to learn both and one without the other is incomplete. End of story.

Comment: @ichangedmyid But then you are missing out on the hydration, the protein and the calcium!

Comment: @DoubleAA unfair argument, no one is making it incumbent upon you to eat the chocolate milk, however if one can only learn one way or the other [and the OP is asking in such a case] then a choice HAS to be made.

Comment: @yehuda Nope, my given case was you are going to drink one or the other (I can decide the givens of my hypothetical case). Now which one do you pick?

Comment: @DoubleAA that's a fair answer. You can certainly say that if you have only 1 hour to learn you should divide it between iyun and bekiyus but in practical terms you will accomplish little in either derech that way. My question differs from chocolate milk because one comes at the expense of the other

Comment: @nikmasi The chocolate milk case as well has one come at the expense of the other because you have to eat one and only one of the two foods. Whichever you choose, you exclude the other.

Comment: @DoubleAA then I would go wit ichangemyid and have the chocolate. and now i'm not sure i understand your comparison. if you are forced to pick one you will certainly be lacking in what the other provides. But so what? The question is do chazal say which you should pick if confronted with that choice. I know they do about torah, not so sure about chocolate milk though

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/50351

Comment: Don't know if this is what you were asking, but it is always important to _think about what you are learning_. Whichever mefarshim you use, spend a lot of the time getting them straight. Don't let a discussion about Rashi vs. Pnei Yehoshua distract from this. It's wonderful that so many people learn daf yomi, but go to any daf yomi shiur: not criticizing, it is wonderful that they're going, but so many people go for years and never learn how to learn or think at all.

Comment: My rosh yeshiva Rav Plutchok a"h used to say, people can do bekius with a lot of mefarshim (this is what the Rashba says, this is what the Pnei Yehoshua says), and they can do iyun with Rashi. Iyun means to think about it.

Answer (score 6):

The גמרא on :דף ה in  [חגיגה](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l2b01.htm) says:

> תנו רבנן שלשה הקב"ה בוכה עליהן בכל יום על שאפשר לעסוק בתורה ואינו
>   עוסק ועל שאי אפשר לעסוק בתורה ועוסק ועל פרנס המתגאה על הצבור

Hashem cries daily for 3 people: those who can learn and don't, those who can't learn and do, and a haughty community leader.

Rav Elyashiv explains (in the [Sefer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Shalom_Eliashiv#Published_works) summarizing his shiurim):

1. Those who can learn and don't: those who could learn b'Iyun and rather "do the Daf Yomi". Rather they should be learning in-depth instead of trying to cover ground.
2. Those who can't learn and do: those who don't have the foundation to learn in-depth, as they have no gone over the Talmud even once, yet do so, thereby wasting their time.
3. A haughty community leader: since the punishment for this person is that his children will be in the category of עם הארץ.

This then explains why the above section follows a discussion about ביטול תורה. If you're learning b'Iyun when you're still at the b'Kiyus stage, or vice-versa, you’re essentially doing ביטול תורה at some level.

Answer (score 4):

The Gemara in [Horiyos 14a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=28&daf=14&format=pdf) queries which of these two people are better for the world. (See Tosafos Harosh there). So if you were one of the last learners in the Torah world and we were dependent on you, then this is Nogea. The Gemara says Rabbah was an Oiker Harim. Rashi explains he was sharp and made analytic arguments in learning. Rav Yosef however was known as Sinai. This is because he knew all the Torah like it was given from Sinai but couldnt debate an arguable matter as well as his contemporary could. The Gemara ends that a Sinai is better because in the end of the day we always fall back onto what was said at Sinai and so the gain of breadth of knowledge out-ways the benefits of an analytic brain.

Comment: No, the Gemara does _not_ query this point. It asks if given two people, one who is a Sinai and one who is an Oker Harim, who do you give precedence to in terms of the honor due to a talmid chacham.

Comment: Also it's not clear if this decision would apply today when all the breadth knowledge is pretty secure on papers and digitally, so perhaps it isn't as important to be in people's heads.

Comment: @DoubleAA first of all the OP did not specify that he is asking for only our generation. Regarding your point of honor the Gemara is still Mashmah that we need one more then the other. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @DoubleAA It's not so important to be in peoples heads!? תנו רבנן ושננתם שיהו דברי תורה מחודדים בפיך שאם ישאל לך אדם דבר אל תגמגם ותאמר לו אלא אמור לו מיד

Comment: @Yehoshua I didn't say "not so important" I said "not as important". Of course it's important. See my comments to the question where I point out that we need both Iyun and Bekiut. That is pashut. I'm just wondering whether this gemara's conclusion is still correct nowadays.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree to some extent in what you are saying. I used to always think about the Gemorah and wonder which one really is more important. However now a days it's pashut that one needs to have both, Sinai and Oker Harim. To have a big bekius isn't enough (as you point out that everything is so readily available -- not such a chiddush anymore especially since everything is at our finger tips in many ways.) A person needs to have the "oker harim" to be able to sift through all of the bekius and determine what the halacha is, be m'demah milsa l'milsa, a good savarah, sechel yosher, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is a misconception in the question. This refers to a person who is capable of doing both what should he do. The gemoro c'subos 103b should be mentioned that rebbi considered R Chiya greater than R Chanina who could be termed 'oker horim'. R Chiya went and taught children different parts of the chumash and mishna and then told them to teach each other. Was there no one else who could do it except the great R Chiya who surely had better things to do. The answer is like I previously wrote, the first thing is to be capable of learning. For that one needs the best rebbe possible and only then can one transmit it further. To be able to learn properly is not an easy thing and takes years of experience. One has to learn the blat then look at the maharsha and ask oneself, now why didnt I think of that. 
So my answer to the above question is, first learn how to learn properly, and then ask the question again. I think by then you will know the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as the old story goes - the questioner should learn neither, he should learn Mussar. After learning Mussar properly, he/she will realize that there is time for both *b'iyun* and *b'kius* learning.

Based on the Bavli, Megilla 6b

> ואמר ר׳ יצחק אם יאמר לך אדם יגעתי ולא מצאתי אל תאמן לא יגעתי ומצאתי אל תאמן יגעתי ומצאתי תאמן הני מילי בדברי תורה אבל במשא ומתן סייעתא הוא מן שמיא ולדברי תורה לא אמרן אלא לחדודי אבל לאוקמי גירסא סייעתא מן שמיא היא
>
> Rav Yitzchak said, "If a person tells you, 'I have tried and not succeeded.' Don't believe him. 'I have not tried and I have succeeded.' Don't believe him. 'I have tried and succeeded.' Believe him. These statements are regarding Torah study, but regarding business he is helped from heaven. And regarding Torah learning this statement can only be said about learning which sharpens a person, but regarding memorization he is helped from heaven.

With this in mind, it would seem that one should engage in *b'iyun* learning as opposed to *b'kius* if one has to choose, because the results of *b'iyun* as a direct results of ones efforts, whereas the results of *b'kius* are not. Theoretically if one learn *b'iyun* his whole life he could both be sharpened and memorize everything, whereas if he only learned *b'kius* he would certainly never be sharpened and may not even memorize everything!

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28379/why-does-sharpening-depend-on-effort-and-memorization-on-divine-assistance).

Answer (score 0):

אגרת לבן תורה (ר' יצחק בן ר"ע יוסף) והן אמת כי ראיתי להגאון מהר"ש קלוגר בהגהותיו לפרי מגדים א"ח אשל אברהם סו סימן קל"ו שהביא מה שכתב האליה רבה שם בשם שיורי כנסת הגדולה בסימן קל'ה הגה"ט אות ט' שתלמיד חכם 
בעל הוראה קודם לעלות לספר תורה לפני תלמיד חכם מפולפל שאינו בעל הוראה וכתב הפרי מגדים על זה דהיינו טעמא כמו שאמרו בהוריות יד דסיני ועוקר הרים סיני עדיף וכתב על זה הגרש"ק לדעתי אין ראיה מהש"ס שבזמנם לא היו ספרים נדפסים משום הכי סיני עדיף אבל עכשיו אחרי מיעוט חיפוש יכול האדם למצוא מבוקשו ולא שייך הטעם דהכל צריכים למרי חטייא לפיכך עוקר הרים עדיף מפני שהוא מוציא מלבו ואי אפשר למצוא ממילא ...

ובארחות צדיקים שער כז כתב והנה בדור הזה נשתכחה התורה כי הלומדים דימו עצמם להיות כמו בעלי התוס' והראשונים והחזיקו לימודם בפלפולים עד שמבטלים את רוב היום בפלפול ומבלבלים זה את זה ועיקר הלימוד שלהם נשאר עראי דעראי וביטול זמן הלימוד קבע והרי אמרו חז"ל שבת סג ליגמר איניש והדר ליסבר ואילו הם אינם עושים כן אלא רצונם ללמוד התוס' וכל התידושים וחידושי חידושים קודם שידעו צורתא דשמעתתא ואיך יצליחו בלימודם ועינינו הרואות כי מרוב טורח העיון והפלפול 
שנוהגים בו רבים פורשים לגמרי מן הלימוד כי ההלכה נעשית להם כמשא כבד לא כן הראשונים אשר תורתם היתה אומנותם והיו ממיתים עצמם עליה יומם ולילה ולבם היה פתוח כפתחו של אולם

מעשה איש (תולדות החזון איש): בנוגע ללימוד הלכות אבילות בימי האבל אמר גיסו מרן בעל קה"י זצ"ל משמו של רבינו שאי אפשר שיהא מותר ללמוד דוקא בלי עיון כי לימוד בלא עיון אינו לימוד [כלומר, אין האבל צריך היתר ללמוד בלי עיון, שהרי לימוד כזה אינו לימוד כלל, ובלא"ה מותר]

See also: דב רפל, ויכוח הפלפול for many sources on the topic.

Comment: It would help a lot of users if you translated this

Comment: This answer basically brings an argument to what is earlier mentioned in the comments that today we have printed seforim.

Answer (score 0):

I once asked Rav [Mendel Weinbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendel_Weinbach) zatza"l a similar question.

The question I asked was: say I have one slot of time available for learning. During that time, I could learn one daf gemara (a full folio, or both sides of the page) with just [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi)'s commentary. Or, I could learn one amud (one side of the page) with [Tosfos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosafot)'s commentary as well. What should I prefer?

Rav Weinbach answer was that it depended on what else I was learning.
If I had time set aside as well for "iyun" (in-depth, analytical study) then this slot should be devoted to "covering more ground" and I should prefer the full daf with Rashi.

If this is the only time I have for Gemara study the entire day, then it's more important to prefer learning an amud with Tosfos.