# Is it better to learn one Mesechta or a few of them?

Tags: torah-study

Is it better to learn one Mesechta and know it very well, or to learn many Mesechtos and know them superficially?

Comment: Define "well" and "superficially". Know one masechta with all of the commentaries possible or a few with just Rashi? Know one's shakla v'taria well or a few with only a section here and there? Know one's shakla v'taria well or a few with only the maskanos?

Comment: What kind of choice is this? Why not work to know all of them well?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22945/learning-biyun-vs-bqius

Comment: @Danno Is this not a dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22595/759

Comment: Could all three be merged?

Comment: are you asking for a beginner who doesnt know how to learn so well?

Comment: When studying practical Halacha the Vilna Goan says that it's better to learn only a little of the Torah but review it many times so that one knows every Halachic detail clearly, rather than learn a lot but not know the Halachah clearly (Chofetz Chaim on the Torah, page 273). I assume one can apply this to learning multiple Mesechtos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rav Moshe Mordechai Epstein the Rosh Yeshiva of Knesset Yisrael of  Slobadka held that its better to learn a small amount but with depth than learning even the whole shas superficially. One who finished Shas can still be called an Am Ha'aretz (ignoramus) if he doesn't understand the logic behind the sugyos. He writes this in his Levush Mordechai (Bava Kama in Hakdama):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you define **well** as knowing it *Bal Pah*,  then we might connect your question to what's *Mekibel* from *Tzadikim* to have this one *Mesechta* that you know ***Bal Pah***, known as the ***Oilem Habah Mesechta***.

Once you have this one Mesechta, the rest will depend on what danno linked regarding learning [B'iyan vs B'qius](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22945/learning-biyun-vs-bqius)